# Compiling bash loadables on cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin

I download bash (5.1) source from : https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/

```
# Both in cygwin and wsl1
./configure && make
```

ran successfully.

When I tried to install with

```
# Ran fine on wsl1
make install
```

I've got following messages on cygwin:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Wl,--export-all -Wl,--out-implib=
print.a  -L./lib/termcap  -o print print.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: print.o: in function `print_bu
iltin':
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:87: undefined reference to `reset_i
nternal_getopt'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:87:(.text+0x28): relocation truncat
ed to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `reset_internal_getopt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /c/Users/philippe/sandbox/b
ash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:88: undefined reference to `internal_getopt'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:88:(.text+0x37): relocation truncat
ed to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `internal_getopt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /c/Users/philippe/sandbox/b
ash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:127: undefined reference to `builtin_usage'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:127:(.text+0x61): relocation trunca
ted to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `builtin_usage'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /c/Users/philippe/sandbox/b
ash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:113: undefined reference to `all_digits'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:113:(.text+0x8b): relocation trunca
ted to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `all_digits'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /c/Users/philippe/sandbox/b
ash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:113: undefined reference to `legal_number'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:113:(.text+0xa7): relocation trunca
ted to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `legal_number'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: print.o: in function `printarg
s':
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:183: undefined reference to `ansics
tr'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:183:(.text+0x19a): relocation trunc
ated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `ansicstr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: print.o: in function `print_bu
iltin':
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:125: undefined reference to `builti
n_help'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:125:(.text+0x259): relocation trunc
ated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `builtin_help'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /c/Users/philippe/sandbox/b
ash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:142: undefined reference to `make_word'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:142:(.text+0x2bc): relocation trunc
ated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `make_word'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /c/Users/philippe/sandbox/b
ash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:143: undefined reference to `make_word_list'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:143:(.text+0x2c7): relocation trunc
ated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `make_word_list'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /c/Users/philippe/sandbox/b
ash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:144: undefined reference to `printf_builtin'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:144:(.text+0x2d2): relocation trunc
ated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `printf_builtin'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /c/Users/philippe/sandbox/b
ash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:146: undefined reference to `dispose_words'
/c/Users/philippe/sandbox/bash-5.1/examples/loadables/print.c:146:(.text+0x2e5): additional reloc
ation overflows omitted from the output
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: print.o:print.c:(.rdata$.refpt
r.list_optarg[.refptr.list_optarg]+0x0): undefined reference to `list_optarg'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: print.o:print.c:(.rdata$.refpt
r.loptend[.refptr.loptend]+0x0): undefined reference to `loptend'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: print.o:print.c:(.rdata$.refpt
r.lcurrent[.refptr.lcurrent]+0x0): undefined reference to `lcurrent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:126: print] Error 1
```

Comment: download the source package of cygwin bash package and look at the patches used for the build. For what I see there are several ones and I doubt they are banal.  https://cygwin.com/packages/x86/bash-src/bash-4.4.12-3-src

Comment: @matzeri Thanks ! Can they work with version 5.1 ? I wanted 5.1 as it has more loadables and other improvements.

Comment: How can I download 4.4.12.3 for cygwin ? I can only see list of files but now download link.

Comment: use setup to download the source or use any mirror eg ftp://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/sources.redhat.com/cygwin/x86_64/release/bash/